# Observer Tool: Processes appear in the Processes List but not in the Applications graph

Tags: elixir

I've opened my project with `iex -S mix` and started my application inside then I run `:observer.start()` to see my processes. The problem is that my application's processes don't appear under the Applications tab, but the do appear in the Processes list.
[image]
[image]

Why could that be?

Comment: Maybe you want to read this http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html and see if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I forgot to define the [application callback](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html#the-application-callback).

Answer (score 2):

The only processes that will appear in the observer graphical applications browser are those started via `proc_lib` functions. This is what all of OTP uses. If you just use normal `spawn` calls, they'll still appear in the full processes list. This is because the system doesn't know how to place these processes into an application's tree because `proc_lib` is what does the bookkeeping for what application it was started from.